# Callback inside an Angular Service - how to return data to controller

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, callback

I am using Google Maps API to get the distance between two points. This method uses a callback function. The problem is that this code lies inside an Angular service, which I want to be called from a controller so the controller can output the results in the scope. But I have no idea how the service can return the resulting **hospitals[]** array of objects to the controller. How can i accomplish this?

```
myAppServices.service('NearestHospitalService', function(){
function calculateDistances() {
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        var hospitals = [];
        service.getDistanceMatrix(
        {
          origins: [origin1],
          destinations: [destinationA, destinationB],
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
          unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
          avoidHighways: false,
          avoidTolls: false
        }, callback);

    }

function callback(response, status) {
        if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
            alert('Error was: ' + status);
        } 
        else {
            var origins = response.originAddresses;
            var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
            var results = response.rows[0].elements;
            for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                hospitals.push(new hospital(destinations[j], results[j].distance, results[j].duration));
            }
            hospitals.sort(compareDistance);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I will add some psuedo code to get you into the right direction. Basically with callbacks you need to have callbacks all the way back to where you want to user your value.

AngularJS have an future/promise module for this as well called $q. I will not use that but you should have a look at it.

```
myAppServices.service('NearestHospitalService', function(){
  var api = {};   
  api.calculateDistances = function(callBack) {
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins: [origin1],
      destinations: [destinationA, destinationB],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    }, extractResult);

    function extractResult(response, status) {
        ... do computations on you response ...
        callback(transformedResponse);
    }
  };

  return api;
});
```

You then call it like this:

```
$scope.distances = [];
NearestHospitalService.calculateDistances(function( ds ) { $scope.distances = ds; });
```

Another way could be to inject $rootScope and use a broadcast if you have multiple components in your code that need to know about something that have been updated so they can extract what they need.

In that case you would cache the response in your service

```
myAppServices.service('NearestHospitalService', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
  var api = {};
  api.distances = [];   
  api.calculateDistances = function() {
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins: [origin1],
      destinations: [destinationA, destinationB],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    }, extractResult);

    function extractResult(response, status) {
        ... once again calculate ...
        api.distances = transformedResult;
       $rootScope.$broadcast('updatedDistances'); // you could also send distances as an argument directly if you wanted to.
    }
  };

  return api;
}]);
```

Then you need to listen to the broadcast and fetch the cache.

```
$rootScope.$on('updatedDistances', function(event) { $scope.distances = NearestHospitalService.distances });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Magnus!

I have a quick question - what is var api = {} doing and why are you returning it?

Comment: It makes it an object with functions. In you example there was no return value from the service at all.

Comment: Thank you. What about function ( ds ) in the controller, what is ds?

Comment: After inspecting this, and implementing your first solution in my code i really doesn't get it to work. I think maybe you have missed something? Please say if i should include more of my code, or make a jsfiddle or something.

Comment: Your solution does not work - and it would be great if you could explain why you are returning the api object, and how the returned api object is going to provide the necessary data in the controller?